# Connect Django to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect Django to the Google cloud SQL, working with python 2.7 and django 1.5 under windows. I went through the instructions on this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

My settings.py file has basic database settings of the form:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'INSTANCE': 'my_project:instance1',
        'NAME': 'my_database',
    }
}
```

With of course a proper could SQL instance and a database created through the SQL prompt of the google apis console

When I try to run `manage.py syncdb` for the first time in order to obtain an OAuth2 token, I get this:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061)")

Before you ask, I did make sure that both the django and google packages are in my PYTHONPATH, as well as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.5"

Any help would be really welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That database configuration only makes sense when connecting from AppEngine. If you want to access your CloudSQL database from your local machine using django, you should use the `google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms` engine.

You can see the different configuration options here:
 https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django#development-settings

**EDIT**: The `google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms` engine has been deprecated. If you want to connect to Google Cloud SQL from your local machine you should use IP connectivity. You can use the Cloud SQL instance IP (IPv4 or IPv6) and connect using the standard `django.db.backends.mysql` engine.

Comment: What about settings for Google Cloud SQL Second Generation? I am unable to get it to [work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34933941/647991)

Comment: I updated the response. You should use IP connectivity to connect from outside of Google.

Answer (score 6):

### Example connection to Google Cloud SQL in Django:

#### `AppEngine Standard, Python 2.7`:

```
try:
    import MySQLdb  # noqa: F401
except ImportError:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection-string>',
            'NAME': '<your-database-name>',
            'USER': '<your-database-user>',
            'PASSWORD': '<your-database-password>',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # DB's IP address
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': '<your-database-name>',
            'USER': '<your-database-user>',
            'PASSWORD': '<your-database-password>',
        }
    }
```

Source: [GCP Python Django Samples AppEngine Standard Python 2.7](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/django/mysite/settings.py)

---

#### `AppEngine Standard, Python 3.7`:

```
# Install PyMySQL as mysqlclient/MySQLdb to use Django's mysqlclient adapter
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers
# for more information
import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/[YOUR-CONNECTION-NAME]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # DB's IP address
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
        }
    }
```

Source [GCP Python Django Samples AppEngine Standard Python 3.7](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/django/mysite/settings.py)

---

#### `AppEngine Flexible`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # If you are using Cloud SQL for MySQL rather than PostgreSQL, set
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql' instead of the following.
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'polls',
        'USER': '<your-database-user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<your-database-password>',
        # For MySQL, set 'PORT': '3306' instead of the following. Any Cloud
        # SQL Proxy instances running locally must also be set to tcp:3306.
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
# In the flexible environment, you connect to CloudSQL using a unix socket.
# Locally, you can use the CloudSQL proxy to proxy a localhost connection
# to the instance
DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '/cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection-string>'
if os.getenv('GAE_INSTANCE'):
    pass
else:
    DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '127.0.0.1' # DB's IP address
```

Source [GCP Python Django Samples AppEngine Flexible](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql)

Comment: Do I need to hardcode password when deploying on GAE standard?

Comment: @Aseem on production you can define environment variables in `app.yaml` file to make them available to your app and import them from `os.environ`.

[Source here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)

Comment: I have used the code above and it runs fine on my localhost, but not on production. I couldn't find any better suggestions anywhere. Please help. @Marta

Comment: Hi @DineshRoy It's been a while since you posted, I'm sorry, I haven't seen it. Did you deployed proper `app.yaml` file?