# Way to query CloudSql from Django app

Tags: django, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to find an effective way to query a Google Cloud SQL database from my Django app. This app is not hosting on App Engine, just on a local server.

I have found a couple of links:

[This one is a generic python connector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Connect_to_your_database)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086517/connect-django-to-google-cloud-sql) mentions a way to do it from a local Django app, but it looks like it is more for testing.

I am not looking to use CloudSQL as my app backend, just make occasional queries to it (probably something daily to read all records in one CloudSQL table, and update a local database with the result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, and not just for testing. You want something like:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'name_of_your_database',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'your_cloud_sql_root_password',
    'HOST': 'assigned_IP_of_your_cloud_sql_instance',
    'PORT': '3306',
  }
}
```

Where name_of_your_database was the database you created with `CREATE DATABASE`.

You may also want to use SSL to protect your data as it goes over the public internet.  To do this [configure SSL for your instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/instances#ssl) and then add the following to the default django database options:

```
    'OPTIONS':  {
      'ssl': {
        'ca': '<PATH TO CA CERT>',
        'cert': '<PATH TO CLIENT CERT>',
        'key': '<PATH TO CLIENT KEY>'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this is pretty much what I ended up cobbling together and it does do exactly what I need. To do SSL would I just do "https assigned_IP"?  (formatting wont let me add the :// without it being invisible)